# View visibility dependent on CheckBox in data binding

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, android-databinding

I want to set a view visibility dependent on a CheckBox checked status. Something like we do in preference.xml.

Currently i am doing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View"/>

        <variable
            name="isScheduleChecked"
            type="java.lang.Boolean"/>

        <variable
            name="activity"
            type="com.amelio.ui.activities.ActivityCart"/>

    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/llDefault"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onCheckedChanged="@{()-> isScheduleChecked}"
            android:text="Checkbox"/>

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/llDefault"
            android:padding="@dimen/space_small"
            android:visibility="@{isScheduleChecked ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE, default = gone}"
            >

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

This does not work. I think `android:onCheckedChanged="@{()-> isScheduleChecked}"` this line is not working. What i am doing wrong? Some tell me best way to implement it.

Currently i am changing isScheduleChecked by my activity in java code like `binding.setIsScheduleChecked(true/false);` but i don't to write code in java class for just set visibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### I did not know the Easiest Way before.

You can refer to id in data binding. No need to take another variable.

```
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Checkbox"/>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/llDefault"
        android:padding="@dimen/space_small"
        android:visibility="@{checkbox.isChecked() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE, default = gone}"
        >

    </LinearLayout>
```

#### Reasons that may cause issue

1. Ids are always generated in `camelCase`. like id is `check_box` then you will use `checkBox.isChecked()`.
2. You must import `View` in layout to use it `View.VISIBLE`

   ```
   <data>
       <import type="android.view.View"/>
   </data>
   ```

If you are having any other issue then you can comment.

Comment: any idea why this one isn't working for me (Alan Todtenkopf answer is)?

Comment: See reasons, I edited answer. Can you also post your error in comment?

Comment: @Khemraj : Not working for me, any idea ? 
                <com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/check" 
                  android:checked="@{eventDetails.needVolunteers}"
                 />
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:visibility="@{check.isChecked() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"

Comment: @Code_Life yes I faced it too.

Comment: @Khemraj: You can have two check listener :( .. one in the check box and other for view visibility ... stupid logic I know but think so that's the problem.

Answer (score 5):

That's a cool idea!  I got it to work by replacing your `onCheckedChanged` line with:

```
android:checked="@={isScheduleChecked}"
```

Comment: I'll check it :), can you tell me what this lamda expression do exactly.

Comment: The "=" between @ and { makes it two-way binding. This means that when you change the value on the view, it changes the variable it is bound to (one way binding would only update the view based on variable change). You can use that to get input text from a user, for example. The `checked` attribute reflects the current state of the CheckBox and will update to true/false based on user checking/unchecking. I tried using the event similar to how you did, but I could only find how to call methods, not assignment expressions. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I would able to test it tomorrow at my office, will mark right for sure if it works. by the way great explanation. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: So i was doing one way binding.

Comment: Thank you so much @Alan, It worked well and i removed extra 10 lines of xml and code that i wrote to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

For those who have tried Khemraj Sharma's solution and not worked, you may try this as it works for me.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Checkbox"/>

<LinearLayout
    style="@style/llDefault"
    android:padding="@dimen/space_small"
    android:visibility="@{checkbox.checked ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE, default = gone}">
</LinearLayout>
```

From Khemraj Sharma's solution, what I have modified is the data binding part. I have changed it

From:

```
@{checkbox.isChecked() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE, default = gone}
```

To:

```
@{checkbox.checked ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE, default = gone}
```

"checked" should be used instead of "isChecked()" as "isChecked()" doesn't work for me.